# Benchmark the performance of file systems

Tags: c, filesystems, benchmarking

I'm taking Computer Organization class this semester.

My professor give us a homework.the description is as follows:

**Write a program to benchmark the two file systems, Windows and Linux. Discuss which performs better.**

I want to use C to implement this homework assignment, but I have no idea how to start.

What functions do I need? What I can do?

Please give me some hints or example.

Comment: take a look at `stdio.h` http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/ and `time.h` http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ctime/ to get some information about how to use files/time in C. Also you are going to have to figure out what you want to test more concretely (i.e. opening a file, deleting a file, creating a file etc).

Answer (score 3):

You could download the sources from [bonie++](http://www.coker.com.au/bonnie++/) and look how they to this.

But i think the best way is that you write to your HDD and look how long it takes to write or read the defined data.

Answer (score 2):

Some interesting data points just for file reads/writes:

- cold cache vs hot cache,
- single-thread? concurrent threads?
- posix aio vs windows overlapped i/o (single thread? multiple threads?)

You might also measure speed of directory enumeration and traversal.

Keep in mind that both Linux and Windows support many filesystems; ext4 and NTFS are the most widely used for Linux and Windows respectively.

What functions should you use? For unix, there's the basic `read(2)` and `write(2)` calls (for normal, blocking IO). Windows has [`ReadFile` and `WriteFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365467%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Is it possible that I use some code some program to benchmark file systems on Windows and Linux ? I am afraid that different functions has different speed.

Comment: The different operating systems have different APIs. Yes, you can use plain C `read(2)`/`write(2)` on both, but you may not get the best possible performance on either.

Comment: I wrote a sequential reading test. code:http://paste.plurk.com/show/991066/
Am I in the right direction ?

Comment: Sort of. The `fopen`/`fread` family of functions does its own buffering — your first `fread` call will read in something like 16kiB of the file, and the next several reads will just copy that. Use system calls (`open`/`read`) instead. Also, 1024b is a very small buffer. To really compare you'll probably want to use something bigger — 16kb-64kb is probably reasonable.

Keep in mind that you probably shouldn't put a 64kb buffer on the stack unless you're sure your system has gigantic amounts of stack space…